# Replicating the Finder selection background on Yosemite?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, osx-yosemite

With OS X 10.10, `VisualEffectView`s were implemented, which allow transparency in your app's UI. It seems though that you can only choose between two styles, a light and dark style (`NSVisualEffectMaterialLight`, and `NSVisualEffectMaterialDark`).

Therefore, assuming you have a `VisualEffectView`, in this case `visualView`, one can use the following to gain the effect used in Finder and many other places.

```
[visualView setAppearance:[NSAppearance appearanceNamed:NSAppearanceNameVibrantLight]];
[visualView setMaterial:NSVisualEffectMaterialLight];
```

However, what if I want to use the slightly darker (but not `NSVisualEffectMaterialDark`) styling used on selected items in Finder. See:

[image: What I want]

How can I accomplish that, as it's not simply a dark, semi-transparent overlay? I've tried playing with the properties of `VisualEffectView`, but to no avail. Apple's docs also seem to be of no use: [NSVisualEffectView](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSVisualEffectView_Class/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the visual effect material to the undocumented value 4.